# jQuery 3 slim ajax basic example

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-3

I'm new to jQuery 3. The following is a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djsuperfive/6ocnfmqn/), working with previous versions of jQuery, but does not work with jQuery 3

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
})
```

In the console, I get this error:

> jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.ajax is not a function TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
>
> jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function(…)

Why ?

Comment: [Just read up about the changes](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#ajax)

Comment: Have you connected with jquery file

Comment: @DavidJorHpan yes of course

Comment: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js` try minified version it runs perfectly with your code.

Comment: @GillesC I did ! but this doesn't help me. The error is '$.ajax is not a function' : I can't even call that method !

Comment: The console log msg is that it .ajax is not there. Are you sure slim version has ajax? Try including with full.jquery library version three. And make.sute.that it's included.

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal thanks

Comment: My pleasure. @MaximeFreschard

Comment: Does anyone know what could cause this error when slim is not used? (Full jQuery min is correctly loaded)

Answer (score 30):

jQuery 3 slim version doesn't support ajax.

According to the [release docs](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/),

> Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the ajax and
>   effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version that excludes these
>   modules. All in all, it **excludes ajax**, effects, and currently
>   deprecated code.

To use `.ajax` method, simply use the full version one.

Here's the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ocnfmqn/3/)

Comment: Just to add to this: To replace jquery slim in the original fiddle, click External Resources on the menu on the left to remove and add jQuery resources. (It wasn't immediately obvious to me how to remove jQuery slim)